# Waitbar in horizontal steps, matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to modify this code

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');

for i=1:10, % computation here %  waitbar(i/10) end
close(h)
```

How can I divide waitbar in 10 steps . I mean  it should look like

```
-------------------
| | | | | | | | | |
-------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will allow you to add vertical lines to your [waitbar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/waitbar.html):

```
hWait = waitbar(0,'Progress');  %# Create the waitbar and return its handle
hAxes = get(hWait,'Children');  %# Get the axes object of the waitbar figure
xLimit = get(hAxes,'XLim');     %# Get the x-axis limits
yLimit = get(hAxes,'YLim');     %# Get the y-axis limits
xData = repmat(linspace(xLimit(1),xLimit(2),11),2,1);  %# X data for lines
yData = repmat(yLimit(:),1,11);                        %# Y data for lines
hLine = line(xData,yData,'Parent',hAxes,...  %# Plot the lines on the axes...
             'Color','k',...                 %#   ... in black...
             'HandleVisibility','off');      %#   ... and hide the handles
```

After running the above code and then doing `waitbar(0.35,hWait);`, you will see a figure like this:

[image]

**NOTE:** The black lines in the plot (both the vertical lines I added *and* the already existing box around the progress bar) will intermittently appear above or below the red progress bar when it is updated. This seems like an existing bug with how [WAITBAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/waitbar.html) behaves, and I have yet to find a workaround to correct it. However, there are quite a number of alternatives that can be found on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=progress%20bar), so I'd certainly check those out if the built-in function doesn't do it for ya. ;)

Comment: Thanx, it works fine.You have cleared an other  point also. There should be definetly a solution of this.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can restart from zero at anytime and update the message. For instance:

```
h = waitbar(0, 'Please wait...');
for step=1:10
    waitbar(0, h, ['Step ' num2str(step) '/10 - Please wait...']);
    for i=1:100
        % Work...
        waitbar(i/100, h);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to add steps to the waitbar itself, but you can add a dynamic message that changes to show how much of the computation is complete:

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...0% complete');
for i = 1:10
    % Computation here
    waitbar(i/10, h, sprintf('Please wait...%d%% complete',100*(i/10)));
end
close(h);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `waitbar` is a built-in function with low flexibility, I think there is no simple way to make the waitbar look like that you want. If it really matters, you can draw a waitbar in several progress mode and save it as a picture. then you can load the pictures in a simple gui that looks like a waitbar! ;)